# Can't find Approval-Sharepoint workflow 2013 template

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013, workflowservice

I am using Sharepoint 2013 and the Sharepoint Workflow Manager 2013. I want to create a workflow using the **Approval-Sharepoint 2013** template. But I can't find it. I've searched on the web for a solution, and many sites recommend going through the steps I outline below, which I did:

At the site collection level I go to Site Settings -> Site collection features

Activate the following:
Disposition Approval Workflow
Publishing Approval Workflow
Workflows

When I go to select a template, this is what I see in the menu (an asterisk indicates a 2010 template):

*Approval - SharePoint 2010
*Collect Feedback - SharePoint 2010
*Collect Signatures - SharePoint 2010
*Disposition Approval
*Publishing Approval
*Three-state

I see no 2013 templates, particularly the Approval-Sharepoint 2013 template which is what I need.

Some sites I've researched have said there is no Approval-Sharepoint 2013 template, but that would contradict Microsoft's own website ( https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742?CTT=1&CorrelationId=4744d23f-ce35-4c48-b367-a8c8380dafbe&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US )  which says:

> Select the Approval – SharePoint 2013 template.
>
> NOTE    If the Approval – SharePoint 2013 template doesn’t appear in
>   the list, contact your SharePoint administrator to find out about
>   having it activated for your site collection or workspace.

Any clues?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Everything was in order  as per the numerous blog posts I had read and I still couldn't get the SharePoint 2010 Approval workflow. After calling Microsoft I realised that the Approval workflow is only available for the Enterprise version.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-the-workflows-included-with-SharePoint-D9C46B8A-9835-4076-B5D3-6412CE4CA0DC?CID=3dcae5e3-f4cc-425d-8fc4-d8b59069578e&SrcID=MOP.CSR

> With SharePoint Server 2010, and with SharePoint Online for Office 365
>   for enterprises, all five of the following workflow types are
>   included. With SharePoint Online for Office 365 for small businesses
>   and professionals, however, only the Three-state workflow type is
>   included.

So first check what version of Sharepoint you have before driving yourself nuts about this workflow.

Comment: For real? That's terrible